Watch a lwp-download activity in the audit.log
I've installed the lwp-download package on Debian 11 and add some rules into auditd custom.rules file.
-i
--reset-lost

-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -F exe=/usr/bin/lwp-download -k github_bash
-w /usr/bin/lwp-download -p rwxa -k github_bash

-e 1

Next, I've restarted the auditd service
augenrules --check && augenrules --load && auditctl -l
auditd

No errors in journalctl.
And I've ran the command
lwp-download -a https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redcanaryco/atomic-red-team/master/atomics/T1059.004/src/echo-art-fish.sh

But there're no EXECVE or PROCTITLE, or other loglines for the lwp-downloadcommand.
But the same rules work for wget and curl properly.
So, is any way to log that command in auditd?
